# Mi animación CSS no funciona aunque la sintaxis y la lógica parecen estar bien

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estaba intentando hacer una animación CSS para una prueba y no consigo hacer que funcione, aunque he revisado el código, he comparado con otras animaciones que sí han funcionado y he probado varias formas que he visto en otras partes que han funcionado, pero nada.

Intentaba hacer algo simple por ahora para probar las animaciones: mover el `<h1 class="lorem4">` en 50px hacia la derecha, pero no funciona.

Este es el código a ver si tiene alguna falla o si falta algo y no me he dado cuenta:

```css
* {
    background: #83B9B8;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 22.5px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 17.5px;
}

#global-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    color: #461313;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 95%;
}

@media (min-width: 288px) {
    .global-container {
        max-width: 240px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 408px) {
    .global-container {
        max-width: 360px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 528px) {
    .global-container {
        max-width: 480px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .global-container {
        max-width: 720px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 848px) {
    .global-container {
        max-width: 800px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .global-container {
        max-width: 960px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .global-container {
        max-width: 1140px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1248px) {
    .global-container {
        max-width: 1200px;
    }
}

#container-1 {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: justify;
}

#container-1 .lorem1,
#container-1 .lorem2,
#container-1 .lorem3 {
    border: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.lorem1,
.lorem2,
.lorem3 {
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    text-align: justify;
}

.lorem4 {
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-animation-name: lorem4;
    -moz-animation-name: lorem4;
    -o-animation-name: lorem4;
    animation-name: lorem4;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 10s;
    -o-animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-duration: 10s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes lorem4 {
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }

    to {
        left: 50px;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes lorem4 {
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }

    to {
        left: 50px;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes lorem4 {
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }

    to {
        left: 50px;
    }
}

@keyframes lorem4 {
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }

    to {
        left: 50px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Flexbox test 2.css">
    <title> Prueba 1 </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="global-container">
        <div id="container-1">
            <h1 class="lorem1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non dolore voluptatum sequi laboriosam saepe? </h1>
            <h2 class="lorem2"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, necessitatibus, cum. </h2>
            <h3 class="lorem3"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing, elit. Eius veritatis, cum quas animi totam eaque distinctio perferendis nobis repudiandae dolore, alias fuga corporis aut quasi iusto natus debitis obcaecati nihil. </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="container-2">
            <h1 class="lorem4"> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br>Autem harum cum tempora consequuntur veniam doloribus <br>distinctio quia necessitatibus nobis, <br>eligendi optio nulla temporibus esse tempore! </h1>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No estás enlazando bien la ruta de tu archivo css, asegurate de que el nombre y ubicación de tu archivo css estén correctas: `href="/Flexbox/test2.css"`

Comment: La estoy enlazando correctamente, puede verse cuando se ejecuta el código que hay tres elementos con bordes y el fondo en turquesa, cosas que en el html no especifiqué.

Comment: Claro porque el snippet de SOes no necesita que estén enlazados los css a través de una ruta. Mira [esta documentación](https://uniwebsidad.com/foro/pregunta/16/como-enlazar-los-css-con-html/)

Comment: Eso lo sé, pero en mi archivo local están bien, he estado probando otras cosas mientras tanto y está funcionando.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando trabajes en herramientas de desarrollo y ver los resultados en tu navegador, recuerda enlazar bien la ruta de tu archivo `.css`.

En este caso, si tu archivo css estaría en una carpeta llamada `Flexbox`:

```
Flexbox
|
|_ _ test2.css
   
index.html
```

La forma de enlazar el `css` tu archivo en tu archivo `html` sería:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Flexbox/test2.css">
```

Ahora volviendo a tu problema, no necesitas hacer todo este código:

```
@-webkit-keyframes lorem4 {
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }

    to {
        left: 50px;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes lorem4 {
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }

    to {
        left: 50px;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes lorem4 {
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }

    to {
        left: 50px;
    }
}

@keyframes lorem4 {
    from {
        left: 0px;
    }

    to {
        left: 50px;
    }
}
```

Simplemente tendrías que utilizar la **pseudo-clase** [**`:hover`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:hover), con esto haces que ocurra algo cuando pases el mouse por encima del elemento. Le ponemos la propiedad `transform` para que el elemento se mueva `50px` a la derecha cuando pasemos el mouse encima.

```
.lorem4:hover {
  transform: translate(50px,0);
}
```

Ahora, hay que darle una transición para que se vea mejor el resultado del movimiento a la derecha, esto iría encima del `:hover`:

```
.lorem4 {
    left: 0px;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

Tu código final resultaría así:

```css
* {
    background: #83B9B8;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 22.5px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 17.5px;
}

#global-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    color: #461313;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 95%;
}

@media (min-width: 288px) {
    .global-container {
        max-width: 240px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 408px) {
    .global-container {
        max-width: 360px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 528px) {
    .global-container {
        max-width: 480px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .global-container {
        max-width: 720px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 848px) {
    .global-container {
        max-width: 800px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .global-container {
        max-width: 960px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .global-container {
        max-width: 1140px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1248px) {
    .global-container {
        max-width: 1200px;
    }
}

#container-1 {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: justify;
}

#container-1 .lorem1,
#container-1 .lorem2,
#container-1 .lorem3 {
    border: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.lorem1,
.lorem2,
.lorem3 {
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    text-align: justify;
}

.lorem4 {
    left: 0px;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.lorem4:hover {
  transform: translate(50px,0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Flexbox/test2.css">
    <title> Prueba 1 </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="global-container">
        <div id="container-1">
            <h1 class="lorem1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non dolore voluptatum sequi laboriosam saepe? </h1>
            <h2 class="lorem2"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, necessitatibus, cum. </h2>
            <h3 class="lorem3"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing, elit. Eius veritatis, cum quas animi totam eaque distinctio perferendis nobis repudiandae dolore, alias fuga corporis aut quasi iusto natus debitis obcaecati nihil. </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="container-2">
            <h1 class="lorem4"> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br>Autem harum cum tempora consequuntur veniam doloribus <br>distinctio quia necessitatibus nobis, <br>eligendi optio nulla temporibus esse tempore! </h1>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Enlaces:**

> ***Hover:*** https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:hover
>
> ***Transition:*** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: Y como comentario añadir que es buena práctica **no usar espacios en los nombres de los archivos**!

Comment: Claro, también, me faltaba mencionar eso.

Comment: Cierto, aunque aún así lo demás me funciona, he probado varias cosas más y todo va bien así.

Comment: Respecto a lo que mencionaste sobre la pseudoclase :hover, eso ya lo sé, pero lo que intento es probar las animaciones porque gradualmente iré haciendo cosas más complejas que con una transición no se pueden hacer.

Comment: Puedes hacerlo también con eso, ya sea para un elemento o varios...

Comment: Que yo sepa con las transiciones no se pueden hacer cosas muy complicadas, son más bien lineales. En cambio a las animaciones puedes definirles de forma precisa muchos estados entre el inicio y el fin de las mismas.

Comment: También puedes utilizar animaciones con hover, yo solo apliqué la transición para mejorar el resultado de tu ejemplo.

Comment: Ah claro, eso es cierto. Pero el punto que intento aclarar es cómo lograr que mi animación funcione bien, porque sigo intentando y no funciona, aunque otros cambios que he hecho han funcionado.